# Search of fertile land or lands?

Tags: grammar, nouns, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

In this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=40&v=iWDKsHm6gTA

It says:

> Groups of people that shared a single language and culture 
>   often split into smaller tribes, 
>   going separate ways **in search of fresh game and fertile land**.

Why they don't search fertile **lands**? Is it ok to use **lands** there?

Comment: It depends whether you are talking about specific land areas (that would be *fertile lands*) or just some land somewhere (that would be *fertile land*). Your example seems to be the second one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Land" is an uncountable noun - I think you know this, since you tagged the question with that tag.  So the normal use of the word would be "..fertile land."   Sometimes the term "lands" is used to mean something like "countries" or "islands" - when referring to far off places to give a strong sense of the unknown.  That use is quite formal sounding, and perhaps a bit old fashioned and doesn't occur often in modern English usage.

> in search of fresh game and fertile **land**

is correct in this case.